# Give data from database in table numbers

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have a foreach in the table. I foreach a row for every row in my database. So my database has got 10 records, I and my table is showing all those records underneath eachother. So far so good.

I want to number them, from 1 to 10, displayed in front of every row.

This is my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped mt-3">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Team</th>
          <th scope="col">Player</th>
          <th scope="col">P</th>
          <th scope="col">W</th>
          <th scope="col">D</th>
          <th scope="col">L</th>
          <th scope="col">GF</th>
          <th scope="col">GA</th>
          <th scope="col">GD</th>
          <th scope="col">P</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php $count =  count($table); ?>
        <?php foreach($table as $t): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++;)
                {
                   echo $i; ?>} 
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $t['team']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['speler']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['gw']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['w']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['g']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['v']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['dv']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['dt']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['ds']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t['points']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is my method

```
 public function fifaLeagueTable() {
    $getTable = "SELECT * FROM fifa_league ORDER BY points DESC";
    $table = $this->model->readAll($getTable);
    $count =  count($table);
    include('app/views/fifaLeagueTable.php');
 }
```

If I var_dump the $count, I receive int(10). So it's counting the amount of rows and I have access to the 10. I am getting a white page, so there might be something wrong in the for loop or something. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your `$table` array might be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create one more variable and its done. Here is updated code :

```
  <table class="table table-striped mt-3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Team</th>
      <th scope="col">Player</th>
      <th scope="col">P</th>
      <th scope="col">W</th>
      <th scope="col">D</th>
      <th scope="col">L</th>
      <th scope="col">GF</th>
      <th scope="col">GA</th>
      <th scope="col">GD</th>
      <th scope="col">P</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $count =  count($table); $num = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach($table as $t): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $num; ?> 
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $t['team']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t['speler']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t['gw']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t['w']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t['g']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t['v']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t['dv']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t['dt']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t['ds']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t['points']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php $num++ ; endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```